# Oracle PL/SQL Function - caller declares parameter values => function returns equation solution

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I want to create a function where a caller can declare 4 parameters and PL/SQL will solve an equation that uses these parameters. My current code is:

```
create or replace function get_distance(
  p_y1 in number,
  p_x1 in number,
  p_y2 in number,
  p_x2 in number)
return number
as
begin
return SQRT(power(p_x2 - p_x1) + power(p_y2 - p_y1));
end;
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in the return-statement but this far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function `power()` accepts two parameters.

The base and the exponent.

```
power(base, exponent)
```

like, `power(100, 2)` = `10000`

So, your power function should be like `power(p_x2 - p_x1, 2)`, I mean your are missing second parameter in the function `power()` , second parameter should be a value according to your logic.

For more Detail Click : [Oracle Power Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/power.php)